# WPF Path : How to Draw this in XAML?

Tags: wpf, path

I want to create a custom GroupBox with non rectangular header like in the following picture :

[image]

As you see, the content of the header must be parametrable, so image, title and background  can be entered in xaml.

Thanks in advance.

---

Thank you for your answer.

Actually i want to use this design in a custom groupbox, so in your answer if i dont't set width and height of the grid (width=150 height =30) the shape components become separated, So i want the shape to be in a unique Body, so it will be easy to apply background colors. and by the way can you round corners like the following picture ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
  <Grid Width="150" Height="30">
    <Border CornerRadius="15,0,0,0" Background="SkyBlue" Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>                    
    <Path Data="M 100,0 L 150,40 L 100 40 Z" Fill="SkyBlue"></Path>
    <TextBlock Text="&#xE161;" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Symbol" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Configuration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

**Explanation**

I have used border as border has cornerRadius property.

```
<Border CornerRadius="15,0,0,0" Background="SkyBlue" Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
```

[image]

And path data is

```
  <Path Data="M 100,0 L 150,40 L 100 40 Z" Fill="SkyBlue"></Path>
```

[image]

Using coordinate system ,i have use started point M 100,0 as border with is 100 and i used 40 for path height in data and 150 for grid total grid width. and **Z** used for close path data.
[image]

**Final Output**

[image]

**Update**
You can use viewbox to scale this drawing as per requrement and i have added rounded curve also

**1st method**

```
<Viewbox>
<Grid Width="150" Height="30">
    <Border CornerRadius="20,0,0,0" Background="SkyBlue" Height="30" Width="103" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
    <Path Name="myPathShape" Fill="SkyBlue" >
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="MyEllipseGeometry"  Center="90,45" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="50"  />
        </Path.Data>        
    </Path>
    <TextBlock Text="&#xE161;" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Symbol" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Configuration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

**2nd method**

```
    <Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="150" Height="30">
        <Border CornerRadius="15,0,0,0" Background="SkyBlue" Height="30" Width="103" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Border>
        <Path Data="M98.625,0.25 C104.076,-1.14832 109.448,2.02746 114.75,9.25 L130.125,29.8739 L102.25,29.9989" Fill="SkyBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30.073" Margin="98.625,-0.073,0,0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="31.5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="&#xE161;" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Symbol" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="Configuration" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>      
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: border has cornerradius property.see border in answer.you can assign value as you need.i have assigned 15.

Comment: I tried 15,2,0,0 but in this case the path become separated from the border

Comment: 2nd Method is what i need, it works fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: Would be easier to do in blend with the pen tool nowadays.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera 2nd method have done using blend with pen tool only.